# Openframeworks Global Lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, openframeworks

I'm working on an openframeworks project that has a series of cubes illuminated by a point light inside of each cube. The transparency of the cubes is reduced to let the light through. I've verified that the light is set at 0,0,0 (which is the center of the cube).

In theory, the point light should illuminate each side of the cube equally. However, the cubes are clearly darker on one side, and lighter on the other.

[image]

So, I'm wondering if there is a global light parameter that I'm not aware of that needs turned off somehow. My code is as follows:

cube.cpp

```
#include "cube.h"

cube::cube(float _w, float _h, float _d, float _cubeHue)
{
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
    d = _d;
    cubeHue = _cubeHue;

    GLfloat vdata[8][3] = {
        {-w, -h, -d}, {-w, h, -d},
        {w, h, -d}, {w, -h, -d},
        {-w, -h, d}, {w, -h, d},
        {-w, h, d}, {w, h, d}
    };

    GLint indices[6][4] = {
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {3, 5, 4, 0},
        {3, 5, 7, 2},
        {0, 4, 6, 1},
        {1, 2, 7, 6},
        {5, 4, 6, 7}
    };

    cubeColor = ofColor();
    cubeColor.setHsb(cubeHue,ofRandom(500,255),ofRandom(100,255), 150);

    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        mesh.addVertex(ofVec3f( vdata[i][0], vdata[i][1], vdata[i][2] ));
        mesh.addColor(cubeColor);

        for (int i=0; i<6; ++i)
        {
            mesh.addIndex(indices[i][0]);
            mesh.addIndex(indices[i][1]);
            mesh.addIndex(indices[i][2]);
            mesh.addIndex(indices[i][3]);
        }
    }

    ofEnableLighting();

    pointLight.setPointLight();
    pointLight.setAttenuation(0.5f);
    pointLight.setPosition(ofVec3f(0,0,0));

    myVbo.setMesh(mesh, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void cube::draw()
{
    pointLight.enable();

    myVbo.drawElements(GL_QUADS, 24);
    mesh.drawWireframe();

    pointLight.disable();
}

void cube::update()
{

}

void cube::setLocation(float _x, float _y, float _z)
{
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
}
```

testApp.cpp

```
#include "testApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    ofBackground(33, 33, 33);
    ofSetFrameRate(24);

    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(1900);
    camera.setPosition(ofVec3f(0,0,0));
    camAngle = 0;
    camX = 400;
    camY = 0;
    camZ = 400;

    cube1 = new cube(50,50,50,75);
    cube2 = new cube(50,50,50,220);
    cube3 = new cube(50,50,50,80);
    cube4 = new cube(50,50,50,190);
    cube5 = new cube(50,50,50,120);

    rotateAngle[0] = 0.0f;
    rotateAngle[1] = 0.0f;
    rotateAngle[2] = 0.0f;
    rotateAngle[3] = 0.0f;

    ofFloatColor diffuseColor;
    diffuseColor.set(1.0,1.0,1.0);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update()
{
    camAngle += 0.02f;

    if (camAngle >= 360)
    {
        camAngle = 0;
    }

    camX = 800 * sin(camAngle);
    camZ = 800 * cos(camAngle);
camera.lookAt(ofVec3f(0, 0, 0));
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw()
{
    camera.begin();

    camera.setPosition(ofVec3f(camX, camY, camZ));

    rotateAngle[0] += 1.0f;
    rotateAngle[1] += 0.5f;
    rotateAngle[2] += 0.75f;
    rotateAngle[3] += 1.5f;

    if (rotateAngle[0] > 359)
    {
        rotateAngle[0] = 0.0f;
    }

    if (rotateAngle[1] > 359)
    {
        rotateAngle[1] = 0.0f;
    }

    if (rotateAngle[2] > 359)
    {
        rotateAngle[2] = 0.0f;
    }

    if (rotateAngle[3] > 359)
    {
        rotateAngle[3] = 0.0f;
    }

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(20,20,-30);
    cube1->draw();
    ofPopMatrix();

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(100,-80,30);
    cube2->draw();
    ofPopMatrix();

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(150,80,100);
    cube3->draw();
    ofPopMatrix();

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(-150,180,-10);
    cube4->draw();
    ofPopMatrix();

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(250,-180,-60);
    cube5->draw();
    ofPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because all your lights are created at the origin.

When you `ofTranslate`, those lights are no longer inside the cubes when you render them (they're at the "original origin").

Why don't you use the location members of the cube and move the translation into the cubes, so you can translate the light sources accordingly?

Comment: Shouldn't the lights translation be relative to the cube's translation since it's one object? I replaced the light with a sphere, and the sphere was perfectly centered.

Comment: It's not one object, OpenGL doesn't have objects. The sphere was centered because you rendered it, but lights aren't rendered. What the translation basically does is shifting the whole world so a new place becomes the origin. Since your light source was at (0,0,0), `ofTranslate(20,20,-30);` will render the cube as if *it* were at (0,0,0) and the light at (-20,-20,30).

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize lights needed to be moved independently of rendered items. Works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it by applying the position of the light after translation and rotation, just before draw the object.

```
// ofLight light  
float la = ofGetElapsedTimef()*.1 * RAD_TO_DEG;
light_pos.set( 0,0,0 );
light_pos.x += sin( la ) * rad;
ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate( ofGetWidth() * 0.5f, ofgetHeight() * 0.5f, 0 );
    ofRotate( ofGetElapsedTimef()*.06 * RAD_TO_DEG, 0, 1, 0 );

    // when applied here and not before the pushMatrix
    // the light position is influence by 
    // the current transformation matrix
    light.setPosition( light_pos );

    glColor4f( 1,1,1,1 );
    ofFill();
    ofDrawBox( -300,0,0, 50,50,200 );
    ofDrawBox( 0,-300,0, 50,50,200 );
    ofDrawBox( 300,0,0, 50,50,200 );
    ofDrawBox( 0,300,0, 50,50,200 );
    ofDrawBox( 0,0,0, 200,200,200 );
    glColor4f( 0,0,0,1 );
ofPopMatrix();
```

Result is a point of light moving horizontally in the cubes space.